# How to include conditions in choose

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to either display as shown below Pass or Fail.

The condition to be met to display **Pass** are as follows 
pcaCode='J' and CrimeOfViolence='True' and DateOfBirth is available in xml,

**or** pcaCode='J' and CrimeOfViolence='True' and DateOfBirth is available in xml

**or**
pcaCode='D'**(something other than 'J')** and CrimeOfViolence='False' and DateOfBirth is available in xml .

I should get **Fail** when the following conditions are met

pcaCode='J'** CrimeOfViolence='True' and DateOfBirth is **not** available in xml

**or**

pcaCode='D'**(something other than 'J')** (if this is true then the CrimeOfViolence does not matter whether true or false) and DateOfBirth is not available in xml

My xslt looks like this

```
<xsl:when test="(string-length($vDOB)=0) and (contains(.,'EDP')) and ($gXPDCount=0)">
```

**but I need to add a condition to check** `pcaCode='J'` and 
`crimeOfViolence='true'`

```
<EditReport>
    <EditResult>
        <EditNumber>43</EditNumber>
        <ItemIdentification>DispositionEvent:10/29/2013 14:37:47:610</ItemIdentification>
        <Result>Pass</Result>
    </EditResult>
</EditReport>
```

or

```
<EditReport>
    <EditResult>
        <EditNumber>43</EditNumber>
        <ItemIdentification>DispositionEvent:10/29/2013 14:37:47:610</ItemIdentification>
        <Result>Fail</Result>
    </EditResult>
</EditReport>
```

I have the following xml

```
    <Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="BCA NICS Disposition and Judgment" MessageID="67160076" xmlns="">
    <ControlPoint Timestamp="8/18/2015 10:49:55 AM" UserID="HochJ">SAVE-CR-SENTENCE</ControlPoint>
    <Case InternalID="1616369289" ID="11021511" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
<CaseCategory>CR</CaseCategory>
        <CaseParty ID="1881965" InternalCasePartyID="1632143500" InternalPartyID="1611032586">
            <Connection Word="CHD" BaseConnection="DF"></Connection>
        </CaseParty>
    </Case>
    <Party ID="149225" InternalPartyID="1610000730">
    </Party>
    <Party ID="1881965" InternalPartyID="1611032586">
        <Gender Word="M ">Male</Gender>
        <DateOfBirth Current="true">11/20/1996</DateOfBirth>-->
    </Party>
    <IntegrationConditions>
        <IntegrationCondition Word="BCANICS" Description="BCA NICS messages">
            <NotificationEvent notificationType="BcaNics" pcaCode="D" elementState="Modified" elementName="DispositionEvent" crimeOfViolence="false">XDPEDP</NotificationEvent>
        </IntegrationCondition>
    </IntegrationConditions>
</Integration>
```

xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:mscef="courts.state.mn.us/extfun" extension-element-prefixes="mscef msxsl" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="../General/ExtensionFunctions.xsl"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="gEditPass">Pass</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="gEditWarn">Warn</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="gType">
    <xsl:value-of select="Integration/Case/CaseCategory"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="gXPDCount">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(Integration/IntegrationConditions/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent[.='XDP'])"/>
</xsl:variable>
<!-- If the ClearEditFailures attribute is set to 'true', then any 'hanging' edit failures-->
<!-- from prior updates should be cleared. -->
<xsl:variable name="gEditFail">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Integration/@ClearEditFailures='true'">Pass</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Fail</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <EditReport>
        <!-- Edit NCIS 4 Number 43 -->
        <xsl:call-template name="EditDOB"/>
        <!-- Edit NCIS 5 Number 44 -->
        <xsl:call-template name="EditGender"/>
    </EditReport>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Note: ItemIdentification element needs to be included in the Edit Result even if it is not being used -->
<!-- E D I T   N U M  B  E  R  43 -->
<xsl:template name="EditDOB">
    <xsl:variable name="vDFPartyID">
        <xsl:value-of select="descendant::CaseParty[count(Connection[(@BaseConnection='DF') and (string-length(RemovedDate)=0)])>0]/@ID"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vDOB">
        <xsl:value-of select="descendant::Party[@ID=$vDFPartyID]/DateOfBirth"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="Integration/IntegrationConditions/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent">
        <EditResult>
            <EditNumber>43</EditNumber>
            <ItemIdentification>
                <!-- If not an XPD then clear just this items failures, else clear all edit failures for this message and edit number -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$gXPDCount=0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@elementName"/>
                        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@timestamp"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>*</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </ItemIdentification>
            <Result>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!--Edit here Dateof birth 08/25/2015-->
                    <xsl:when test="(string-length($vDOB)=0) and (contains(.,'EDP')) and ($gXPDCount=0)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$gEditFail"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$gEditPass"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </Result>
        </EditResult>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected result similar to this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<EditReport>
    <EditResult>
        <EditNumber>43</EditNumber>
        <ItemIdentification>DispositionEvent:10/29/2013 14:37:47:610</ItemIdentification>
        <Result>Pass</Result>
    </EditResult>
</EditReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the question I posted earlier today. I used `and` `or` together for `@pcaCode` and `@crimeofViolence`

```
<xsl:when test="(string-length($vDOB)=0) and (contains(.,'EDP')) and ($gXPDCount=0) and ((not(@pcaCode='J')) or (@crimeOfViolence='true'))">
```